# How do I notify a class component of an event?

Tags: java, interface, callback

I have class named A and its component class called B.

```
public class A {
    B myB;

    ...
    public void bWasUpdated(){
       ...
        List<String> list = myB.connections;
    }
}
```

If I have an instance of B in my class A and if that instance of B gets updated somehow, how can I notify my instance of class A and call `bWasUpdated()`?

I tried interfaces but ended up really confused. I guess I don't quite understand how to pass data yet between an object and its component.

**EDIT**

```
public class B {
    ArrayList<String> connections;

    ....

    public void listen(){

        ...
        if(foundNewConnection){
            this.connections.add(theNewConnection);
            //Notify class A about this new connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you exposing `A.myB` to the outside world?  If you are using a _setter_ method, then you will know when the `B` instance has been updated.

Comment: Can you provide more information about class B ?

Comment: Sure, I call class B a ContactManager and it basically is listening, using Sockets, for incoming connections. My instance of b maintains a list of these connections and I want to notify class A when a new connection is made!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean by exposing A.myB? My class A is basically the main class in a sense. And I don't have any other parent classes accessing an instance of A.

Comment: I think you really need to show us some implementation details of class `B`.  Your abstracted question is not enough for a concrete answer IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use a *Listener*, which is a form of the pattern called the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

First, add this interface to your B class:

```
public interface ChangeListener {
    public void onChangeHappened();
}
```

Second, add a listener variable to B with a setter:

```
private ChangeListener listener;

public void setChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Third, make A implement the ChangeListener interface and register itself as a listener:

```
public class A implements ChangeListener {

public A() {
    myB = new B();
    myB.setChangeListener(this);
}

...

public void onChangeHappened() {
    // do something with B now that you know it has changed.
}
```

And last but not least, call your listener inside B when something changes:

```
public void someMethodInB() {
    // change happened
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onChangeHappened();
    }
}
```

Comment: This pattern seems like exactly what I needed! I will give it a try!

Comment: Thank you for this clarifying answer! I definitely understand how to use properly use interfaces better now!

Answer (score 3):

if B - inner class of A, then you can invoke in B setters (or other state-modifiers) **A.this.bWasUpdated();**

Comment: I want to avoid relying on static methods for A.

Comment: well for this answer you don't need static methods. It works just fine without interfaces (if B -inner class of A)